# While cycle create an infinite loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote this PHP code to put on a wordpress page template:

```
<?php 
query_posts('showposts=10&cat=7'); 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?> 

<li class="img-slider"> 
    <?php the_content(); ?> 
</li> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

When I view the page I don't see any result and the right bar of the browser continue to reduce itself. I have understand that the code create an infinite loop.
Where I mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, you should not use `query_posts`. It's too invasive for simple loops, and messes with the entire WP_Query. Also `showposts` should be `posts_per_page`.

**Secondly**, it's hard to gauge what this issue is without more context. Perhaps pastebin your entire page, and edit it into your question. My guess is a loop within a loop, and should stop at like a 100 posts. (10 X 10) but if it's reset anywhere else if could very well go infinite!

Use this code instead to create loops:

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=10' );

if($custom_query->have_posts()) :

    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();

        //global $post; // for stuff like $post->post_name

        // Post stuff here
        // the_title();

    endwhile;

endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Look at the WordPress codex for more details. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Comment: There must be something on the page itself, or perhaps something deep in the theme that is making it not complete the post loop. Please share more code with us via pastebin to get a better idea where the issue could be. Thanks.

Comment: "It doesn't work" says nothing. If you're still running into the same problem, try deleting the query and while loop altogether. If it still "doesn't work" then the problem is not with your query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `if` statement in your loop:

```
<?php 
query_posts('showposts=10&cat=7'); 
if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?> 

<li class="img-slider"> 
    <?php the_content(); ?> 
</li> 
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, I would say that in each loop of the `while` statement, the function is returning the first row of the data? So each time the while loop executes you are calling the function again, which is returning the same row over and over again without actually iterating through the result set.